# Server side Load Balancing with Spring Cloud

Tags: microservices, load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am reading about **Api Gateway** and **Load Balancers**, but I am a bit confused. My questions are the followings:

- Is there a way to add or activate load balancing feature in **Spring Cloud Gateway** in order to implement Server Side load balancing, or the only available solution are *NGINX* or *Traefik*?
- Server side load balancing seems to be the best approach. So what is the best between configuring your own **Load Balancer** or using the Cloud Based **Load Balancer**.
- Should **Api Gateway** and **Load Balancer** be on the same standalone instance or should be two different instances?

Thanks in advance.